# Will this DevOps Q&A site ever graduate?

Tags: discussion, beta

I really worry whether this Q&A site will ever become official as the number of visitors dropped significantly the last two week, from more than 1000 to less than 10 a day. Do other people have this concern as well? What about creating and executing a plan that will increase the number of visitors and to let this Q&A become official eventually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drop you are seeing is due to a bug: [Traffic (views, visits) isn't correctly registered on Site Analytics or Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51) so I don't recommend making any decisions based on these stats.

As for being "official": Stack Exchange is moving toward allowing small sites such as this one to have [own themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) which should put them essentially on par with the rest of the network. The ongoing discussion about removing "beta" label may be resolved by such changes, too.

Comment: Besides the analytics big mentioned before, I am intrigued by the comment made by OP : " What about creating and executing a plan that will increase the number of visitors and to let this Q&A become official eventually?" - what would you have in mind ?

Comment: @BruceBecker could you check my answer? What is your opinion on this?

Comment: Looks like a plan :)

Answer (score 1):

Our current challenges as a community to get out of beta, are: to increase the **number of questions per day** and the **answer ratio**:

[image]

**Plans**

---

*Number of questions per day*

In order to increase the number of questions per day we could leave comments at Q&As on StackOverflow and ServerFault that request users to migrate their Q&A to DevOps SE:

*According to me your Q&A is more on-topic on [DevOps SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions). SO and SF are about software and system engineering respectively.*

---

*Answer ratio*

Every user could try to answer one question a day, even when there is already an answer.